# Are there PPAs with soname bumps?

Tags: ppa, shared-library, testing

Are there any PPAs that bring a library with different *soname* along with its (upgraded) package compared to what is installed in the standard Ubuntu system (i.e. *soname bump*)?  I am especially interested in PPAs available for Bionic and Focal so I can test *ppa-purge* with them in my current system.

Comment: What is "soname"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname - now, i think @jamo needs to explain what he/she actually has in mind; FWIW libaries and their versions are handled by Ubuntu apt updates - if one delves into handling these oneself, it awfully often leads to OS havoc and a need to reinstall.

Comment: @Pilot6 https://askubuntu.com/tags/shared-library/info

Comment: @Hannu current [ppa-purge](https://launchpad.net/ppa-purge) tries to explicitly install a different soname of a library, if it thinks there is one available after disengaging a PPA. I want to test, if that is really needed or could the library soname changes be administrated via dependencies by apt implicitly. [soname handling in ppa-purge](https://git.launchpad.net/ppa-purge/commit/?id=eb366bba8ae2613f591271eb8a33fdacf5f2ad97)

Comment: I'm wondering if your queries belongs in another forum; e.g. one with kernel developers or similar.

Comment: @Hannu This question is not specific to kernels. I have asked this in [ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2473396)